# Python: cannot update @property manually

Tags: python-3.x, properties, setter

The language is Python 3. I am trying to create a class, where every time user updates the attribute *data*, the attribute *alphabet* (symbols that are used in the data) will be updated. I was able to do so using *@property* decorator, but then I cannot update alphabet manually when I need it.

Currently I have the following code:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    @property
    def alphabet(self):
        if self.data:
            upd = self.alphabetize(self.data)
        else:
            upd = []
        return list(set(upd))

    @alphabet.setter
    def alphabet(self, value):
        self.alphabet += value

    def alphabetize(self, data):
        alph = []
        for i in data:
            alph += [j for j in i]
        return list(set(alph))
```

Indeed, it updates *alphabet* when I update *data*:

```
>>> a = Test()
>>> a.data = ["fg"]
>>> a.alphabet
['f', 'g']
```

But when I update *alphabet* manually, it crashes:

```
>>> a.alphabet += ["t"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
<...>
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Can you please help me to figure out how to update *alphabet* when *data* is updated, but also at the same time to be able to manually add items to *alphabet*? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you try setting the `self.data` inside the `setter` method of the property called `alphabet` i.e. `@alphabet.setter`.

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    @property
    def alphabet(self):
        if self.data:
            upd = self.alphabetize(self.data)
        else:
            upd = []
        return list(set(upd))

    @alphabet.setter
    def alphabet(self, value):
        self.data += value

    def alphabetize(self, data):
        alph = []
        for i in data:
            alph += [j for j in i]
        return list(set(alph))

a = Test()
a.data = ["fg"]
print (a.alphabet) # ['f', 'g']

a.alphabet += ["t"]
print (a.alphabet) # ['f', 'g', 't']

a.data = ["abc"]   # over riding alphabet again
print (a.alphabet) # ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Because the property `alphabet` is just a different view of `self.data`.

Working example here: https://ideone.com/xp0jve